# PDE constrained topology optimization

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, oc.optimization-and-control

Just a quick high level question here about the density method in PDE constrained shape optimization. As I understand it, continuous density methods pose an optimization problem of finding a material distribution $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ inside a design domain $\Omega$ which minimizes an objective function $F$ as
\begin{align}
&\min\limits_{\rho} F(\mathbf{u}(\rho),\rho) := \int_{\Omega} f(\mathbf{u}(\rho),\rho) \mathrm{d}V  \\
& G_{i}(\mathbf{u}(\rho),\rho) \leq 0, \quad i=1,...,M  \\
& H_{j}(\mathbf{u}(\rho),\rho) = 0, \quad j=1,...,N  \\
&\rho(\mathbf{x}) \in [0,1] \quad \forall \mathbf{x} \in \Omega. 
\end{align}
Oftentimes the $H_{j}$ are weak formulations of a PDE, for example Poisson's equation. What I am struggling with is how to convert a strong PDE over a domain into a weak one over a material density distribution. For example, Poisson's equation with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions, and a forcing term $-q$ (I might be off by a sign) over a domain $\Omega_{m}$ can be written:
$$
\int_{\Omega_{m}} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \mathrm{d}V=\int_{\Omega_{m}}q \phi \mathrm{d}V \quad \forall \phi \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega_{m})
$$
My question is how one would even begin to reformulate this over a domain $\Omega$ which is defined through a density $\rho(\mathbf{x})$. In the case where $\rho$ is binary, I could see rewriting the weak form above as:
$$
\int_{\Omega} \left( \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \right) \rho \mathrm{d}V=\int_{\Omega}q \phi \rho \mathrm{d}V \quad \forall \phi \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega_{m})
$$
with $\rho$ acting as a cutoff function $-$ but this messes up any "nice" integration by parts formula, and then what space does $\phi$ even belong to? Any ideas are appreciated!